# Super admin access to Huawei HG8247H

Tags: router, wireless-router

I have one of these boxes and the ISP set some password for the super admin account. Initially I wanted to change my DNS to OpenDNS, the feature is disabled, but now that I found out about this account, getting quite concerned about privacy. Someone being able to log in to the router might MITM and steal CC/banking info, snoop on emails and whatnot.

I've tried:
telecomadmin/admintelecom - not working

admin/*6P0N4dm1nP4SS* - not working

This guide: https://zedt.eu/tech/hardware/obtaining-administrator-access-huawei-hg8247h/ - I get kicked out as soon as the ISP settings are downloaded, before I can grab the XML file. And it's not just a redirect, the actual session gets destroyed (tried freezing the page).

The ISP have not created a custom OS image, probably just overriding stuff from their remote server. I know this because if I unplug the fiber and reset to factory, telecomadmin/admintelecom does work until I plug in the fiber and everything gets overwritten again.

Comment: ISPs do push custom firmware. In addition, the ISP owns the box, not you. If you don't like the policy then you need to get a box that YOU own. Doing anything else with their box is likely against their terms of service.

Comment: This particular box (or any other "like it" or "compatible") will have the same settings, to download the configuration remotely from their servers. I have one just like it (different MAC though) and if I call them to use mine instead they will ask for the MAC or ID and let me use mine. But this box will also download their settings ergo I still won't have access to the admin account, but they will, and they can do whatever they please with my network and my box.

Comment: Whether the ISP owns the box or not depends on the contract. Where I live, the ISP sells you the box.

Comment: If you bring your own device, how can the ISP get admin access? A different brand router won't download settings from the ISP.

Comment: Why should the ISP have admin access to my device in my physical location? I don't mind configuring all settings manually, this is a one-off thing anyway.